# Excel Performance Tuning - RAND()

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook that I'm essentially using as a place to log data. Currently it contains about 400 rows, but a new row is added each time I run a process. One of the columns contains `=RAND()` on each row which is used to sort the data in a random order when it gets exported.

Because of the number of `RAND()` calculations, the sheet is starting to take a lot of time to insert each row. I'm wondering if something like `RANDBETWEEN(0,9999)` would be more efficient to serve this purpose - or if there is another alternative that I'm not aware of...

Comment: What is the process to add a row to the sheet? If it is in any kind of a scripting language, could you add a random value to each before it's inserted? Then you wouldn't rely on Excel's volatile functions (which can get slow).

Comment: The problem is not that Rand() is used in each row. The problem is that Rand() is volatile and like all volatile functions will cause a recalculation of the whole workbook as soon as any cell is changed. Rand() itself is a very fast function and does not take any time to calculate.

Comment: @rocksteady Yea it's vb .net which I'm pretty novice at so the best I could figure out was to sort by a column in Excel - which is the only reason I have the column at all. I can insert a new random with each row, but then the sort would be static... In other words, each time I pull data from this Excel file it will have the same sorting because the numbers are static (even though they're random numbers)

Comment: @teylyn perhaps there is a way to prevent the recalculation when cells are changed? I really just need the recalculation when the sheet is either opened or closed...

Answer (score 1):

Rand() is a volatile function and will cause a recalculation of the whole workbook whenever any cell is changed.

You can stop that with the calculation settings in the Formulas ribbon. Set calculation to manual and click the **Calculate Now** or **Calculate Sheet** command when you want to run a recalculation.

Be aware that the setting applies to Excel as an application and will affect all workbooks. This can be dangerous if you forget that you have manual calculation applied and expect results in other workbooks to recalculate automatically.